# Test Error: JSON2Apex method does not exist

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, failing-tests, parsing

Error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: JSON2Apex.parse(String)

I used https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/.  I got back APEX and a test class that should work. I am getting the above error. I have added to the controller so perhaps something is butting heads but I am not sure what direction to go in. Can anyone see anything glaringly wrong with this?

**Class**

```
public class CalloutAgentList {
        //Public String userEmail{ get; set;}
        public JSON2Apex info { get; set; }
        public static String jsonStr {get;set;} 
        public static Datetime changeToPst {get;set;}
        public static String newDate {get;set;}

    //this should return a JSON string
    public static String getAccounts() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://myendpoint.com');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http h = new Http();
        string d = getAuth();
        string e = 'token ';
        string f = e + d;

        req.setheader('Authorization', f );
        try{
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            jsonStr = res.getBody();
            return jsonStr;
        }
        catch(Exception z){
            system.debug('this is the system debug for excception z: ' + z);
            return null;
        }
    }
    //authorizing 
    public static string getAuth() {
        try{
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://gettingatoken.com');
            req.setMethod('GET');      
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'apikey 12345678946563211456');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            System.debug('this is the res: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ', ' + res.getBody());
            return res.getBody();
        }
        catch(Exception q){
            system.debug('this is the system debug for excception q: '+ q);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static String helloKitty = getAccounts();

    //wrapper class 
    public class JSON2Apex 
    {
        public Datetime DateModifiedUtc{get; set;}
        public List<AgentInfoList> AgentInfoList{get; set;}
    }

    public class AgentInfoList 
    {
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public Integer PriorityNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json)  
    {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }

    public CalloutAgentList() 
    {
        info = (JSON2Apex)parse(helloKitty); 
        system.debug('this is the string-->' + info);
        system.debug('this is the string-->' + info.AgentInfoList);
        system.debug('this is the string-->' + info.DateModifiedUtc);
        changeToPst = info.DateModifiedUtc;
        System.debug('This is the Converted Time to PST is ' + changeToPst.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'America/Los_Angeles'));
        newDate = changeToPst.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa' , 'America/Los_Angeles');
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
static testMethod void testParse() {
    String json = '{\"DateModifiedUtc\":\"2016-09-07T20:12:47.1519119Z\",\"AgentInfoList\":[{\"Username\":\"Agent00@gmail.com\",\"PriorityNumber\":0},{\"Username\":\"Agent01@gmail.com\",\"PriorityNumber\":0},{\"Username\":\"Agent02@gmail.com\",\"PriorityNumber\":0},{\"Username\":\"Agent03@gmail.com\",\"PriorityNumber\":0},{\"Username\":\"Agent04@gmail.com\",\"PriorityNumber\":0},{\"Username\":\"Agent05@gmail.com\",\"PriorityNumber\":0}]}';
    //CalloutAgentList obj = CalloutAgentList.parse(json);
    CalloutAgentList.JSON2Apex obj = CalloutAgentList.parse(json);
    System.assert(obj != null);
}
```

Comment: What's the outer class that wraps your first snippet? That's what you need to reference, not the `JSON2Apex` inner class.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have tried using the outer class name (CalloutAgentList ) and get a similar error message. See edits.

Comment: That should work...Can you [edit] your post add the test method where you applied that approach and the verbatim error message?

Comment: Edited. Perhaps it is the JSON2Apex method that the CalloutAgentList is having trouble reading...
the error I am getting with this is: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: CalloutAgentList.JSON2Apex.parse(String)"

Comment: It's supposed to be `CalloutAgentList.parse(...)`.

Comment: Thank you I just got that response from @PranayJaiswal. You are both right, I missed that. Thank you for your detective work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are Not using the Wrapper class name while referring the Inner Json2Apex class .

```
CalloutAgentList.JSON2Apex obj = CalloutAgentList.parse(json);
```

Using Wrapper Class name to refer your inner Apex class will solve the problem.

Comment: ohh...I think you are on to something. I do still get an error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: CalloutAgentList.JSON2Apex.parse(String)" but this is close.

Comment: updated code... with respect to your update of code on orignal post .

This will work :)

Comment: ah great. It was the second JSON2Apex that was erroring out. This worked. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the top level class, which has the static method you are trying to call. For example, if your code looks like:

```
public TopLevelClass
{
    public class JSON2Apex
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
    static JSON2Apex parse(String input)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then in your test, you need to call `TopLevelClass.parse(...)`, not `JSON2Apex.parse(...)`.

```
TopLevelClass.JSON2Apex instance = TopLevelClass.parse(payload);
```